Git's built-in garbage collection vs JGit handling of garbage collection operation ( Built-in Git vs JGit garbage collection mechanism)
Here are the few points :

Git's built-in mechanism automatically triggers the git gc when the number of loose objects are high or it detects repository size is huge and objects should be garbage collected.

Git's garbage collection is by default automatically executed alongside frequently used Git commands like git commit, git pull, and others.


Questions:-

What about the JGit handling of garbage collection ? Does Jgit APIs like PULL, COMMIT...etc automatically trigger git gc internally or is there any configuration to do that ?

If all operations on a local repository are performed through JGit APIs, does it mean that garbage collection may never occur and it must be explicitly triggered from time to time using git gc command or JGit's GC API to reduce repository size ?


A test on local repository shows that by default JGit APIs does not run git gc (opposite to Git's built-in gc as it runs automatically executed alongside frequently used Git commands like git commit, git pull, and others whenever necessary)

JGit is a Git implementation in Java with its own garbage collector. If something is missing, create a pull request for it here.
